# Performance monitoring of production site using Shell script and Selenium Web Drivers

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I will shortly try to explain what I am trying to do here. I need to periodically check the response time of the my site by logging into the system and noting the time to load the welcome page.

I am doing this using `Selenium WebDriver` and `Java`. I am currently checking the response time using the `org.apache.commons.lang3.time.StopWatch` which start when user hits the login button and stops when welcome page renders completely. I check weather this response time is above threshold level and send mail to admin alerting him in case of slow response of system.

Currently, I have created the executable jar file which opens the web browser using Selenium WebDriver  and check the response time. I have also created the job in Jenkins using DOS commands which runs periodically using cron schedular. This I'm doing in my Windows 7 pc and I have Jenkins installed on my localhost. The scheduled job builds on Jenkins periodically but I can't see any activity like opening the web browser and the further task explained above. It runs perfectly when I use windows scheduler to execute batch file. **The ultimate goal I have, is to run the Selenium WebDriver tests on the Linux system via jenkins while Jenkins server has been installed on a Linux machine.**

Any help will be great! Also let me know if anybody wants to see the code.

Comment: Run Jenkins from command prompt as "java -jar jenkins.war" instead of the windows installer version.

Comment: @Priyanshu Shekhar thanks, I initially misunderstood what you said.  What do you mean by running Jenkins from command prompt.

Comment: Your question creates confusion, Could you please clarify it, How you want to run test on Linux machine or You want to test activities on Jenkins installed system?

Comment: I have a common Jenkins server (Linux PC) which we use as CI. On that server I need to run these tests. For testing this I have installed Jenkins on my local machine which is Windows 7.

Comment: You can connect linux system as a slave of Jenkins master by a JNLP agent.Have a look here: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines

Comment: @Priyanshu Shekhar after searching for what you mean in your first comment, I have downloaded the jenkins.war file and run it in command line. But how can I access the jobs created in my windows version or should I have to create new job?

Comment: you need to create new job and don't forget to uninstall previous installation @Vaibhav Katole

Comment: Ok, I tried searching for the options to create new job while running Jenkins from war file but couldn't find a way out?

Comment: You still have not understood me. I suggested you to install jenkins using command prompt as I am assuming you must have done it via a windows installer file (.exe or .msi). So please uninstall that and do a fresh installation of jenkins  by using command prompt and for that you need to download jenkins.war file.

Comment: I did the same thing @PriyanshuShekhar, I just need to add job which will execute commands periocally.